# Exception while trying to connect rabbit mq on aws mq from .net core 5 application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I got this exception while I was trying to connect to rabbitmq. My app is running on .NET 5.
i dont use private vpc i have set the mq to public

> Exception: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Then I debugged the code and found that

> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

It tries to connect from my local machine. I was running rabbit mq locally and it was working fine but when moved to aws I got this exception.

Here are my settings for connecting to rabbitmq service

```
"Connections": {
  "Default": {
    "HostName": "myserver.amazonaws.com",
    "UserName": "username",
    "Password": "password",
    "Port": 5671
  }
}
```

i use event bus that attached with framework that i use to develop my project it is called abp framework here is my code to configure connection

```
Configure<BaseRabbitMqOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Connections.Default.HostName = configuration["RabbitMQ:Connections:Default:HostName"];
            options.Connections.Default.UserName = configuration["RabbitMQ:Connections:Default:UserName"];
            options.Connections.Default.Password = configuration["RabbitMQ:Connections:Default:Password"];
            options.Connections.Default.Port = configuration.GetValue<int>("RabbitMQ:Connections:Default:Port");
            options.Connections.Default.AmqpUriSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
            
            options.Connections.Default.VirtualHost = "/";
        }
       );
```

> **Update**
> i have set my connection to use ssl and now i get this exeption

```
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
```

Comment: Please also show the code that sets up the connection as well; whether you're using EasynetQ or Mass Transit.  Also; we'll need to know whether your VPC is configured to allow you to have IP access to that box.  If you're running RabbitMQ on EC2, your VPC has to be configured to allow your local machine's IP access to that box. To "Whitelist" it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker  i configured vpc to be public i edited the question , i use abp framwork and it has event bus attached with it not masstransit or easynetQ

Comment: none of the code you wrote shows the connection being opened. Can you connect to the rabbitmq management UI if you remote into the server?

Comment: the framework abstract the connection being established , i just give it the configs,  yes i can connect to rabbitmq management ui , i enabled ssl and now it gives me this exception      `AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.` @GeorgeStocker

Comment: it's sounding more and more like you don't have the right settings to connect to your rabbitmq.  RabbitMQ by default does not allow remote connections. If it were me I'd set up a username and password, enable remote connections in the rabbitmq configuration, and do it that way. Setting up SSL takes a bit more configuration; but can be done.  First you want to make sure you can communicate with your RabbitMQ EC2 instance over something, anything.

Comment: read more here about connecting to RabbitMQ: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html if you use guest/guest, you can't connect to it remotely. You have to set up your own user/pass and configure rabbitmq to allow remote connections.

Comment: i'm not using EC2 , instead i use amazon mq service , i have discovered the problem , when i enable ssl i should pass the server name that contains ssl certificate in my situation it was the same host name of the rabbitmq server , thanks for your help @GeorgeStocker

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved by specifying the server hostname in the `SslOption.ServerName` property like this:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password,
    VirtualHost = virtualHost,
    HostName = hostname,
    Port = port,
    Ssl = new SslOption
    {
        Enabled = useSsl,
        ServerName = hostname
    }
};
```

The solution is based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292529/exception-while-trying-to-connect-rabbit-mq-on-aws-mq-from-net-core-5-applicati#comment120715125_68292529) here by OP, I just wanted to add it as an answer for posterity.